# lightweight CI for working copy?

Tags: continuous-integration, filesystemwatcher, building

Is there a lightweight CI that tracks file changes in working copy/folder, instead of monitoring the VCS? I just want it to rebuild/perform series of tasks (quick typos/bugs check, building, formatting, unit testing, etc.), which could be passed as a shell script, and that script is  run on every file change in the folder. If possible, I would like to monitor log/results in the browser on my second monitor.

We use lots of custom tools for many tasks, so suggestions like 'just use Jenkins/Maven/CMake/Whatever standard' does not work :(.

The closest tool I found is [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard), but it seems to not have the live build log in the browser, and is ruby based (never touched any ruby package manager and installation seems complicated/root dependant). Java or C++ based solutions would be better for me.

Answer (score 0):

That's going to be very cumbersome and will produce a lot of false-positives. I don't know about you, but I tend to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> *all the time*, saving in-progress work that even would not compile. This, plus invoking the entire toolchain on effectively *every change* will grind your workstation to a halt.

All kinds of linters/formatters/bundlers are typically run as a part of a pre-commit hook in your VCS of choice. This way you can make all the mess you want while doing your work, but ensure that before files get checked in they are processed according to your internal rules.

Comment: Thanks Anton. I'm a vimmer, so that's :w for me :) Saving/building constantly is ok, it almost repeats my current workflow. With only one exclusion - I have to do it manually. And the first stage is going to be clang-check, which is very quick.